# Linux permissions to run but not read files

Tags: java, linux, bash, security

I currently have a Java based application stored on my CentOS server that is probably worth a lot of money and I need to some how give somebody access to restart the application in case it crashes without allowing them to actually get access to the java class files where they could be compromised.

Was just wondering if there's a way I could do this ? IE if there is a way I could have a jailed shell with commands restricted only to running the bash script that starts the application or if I would need to write a 3rd party application to handle all this for me?

Thanks for reading

Comment: That is fundamentally impossible.  You cannot run a file without reading it.

Comment: @SLaks Linux/UNIX has a permission ("x") to run a file but not necessarily read it (that would be "r"). / I wouldn't be surprised to find Linux supporting executing jar files, but that would seem a bit dicey. I guess you could have a sticky bit set launcher, but it's not necessarily easy to get right.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline: But in order to execute the code, you still need to somehow read it.

Comment: You'd need to do this using something that either filters commands, or a setuid wrapper that then runs the program as a different userid which is allowed to read and execute it.

Comment: Lots of trust going into the people you allow to restart your application which, if it is indeed "worth a lot of money", probably has some contract in place anyway…

Comment: @SLaks I think you may have a point, a shell script with a 001 permission is still readable in Cygwin's bash.

Answer (score 1):

Write a small wrapper which starts the application. The simplest way to do this would be to create a shell wrapper:

```
#!/bin/sh
java ...
```

But it's likely that that won't work on a server installation. See below.

Change the owner and group of the wrapper to a user and group which have permission to read the jar files:

```
$ chown user:group wrapper
```

Change the permissions of the wrapper to make it world-executable, and `setuid` (so that it will run as the owner of the wrapper, set in the previous step):

```
$ chmod a+rx,og-w,u+s wrapper
```

Then the wrapper will be run as the indicated user, without giving anybody additional privileges over the executable or its support files.

I strongly recommend *not* making the owner of the wrapper `root`. Use some user created for this purpose, which you control but which does not have root access.

---

In case your system doesn't honour the setuid bit for interpreters (that is, scripts with a shebang (`#!`) line), here's a simple C wrapper which should work. You'll have to modify it as indicated below and then compile it:

```
cc -Wall -o wrapper wrapper.c
```

(`-o wrapper` means "the binary to produce will be called `wrapper`.) Substitute whatever name you like, and put the wrapper file in a place where it can be found, such as `/usr/local/bin/wrapper`. It's hard to give precise instructions without knowing anything about your system configuration. Good luck.

I have no idea how you run your application, but you'll have to insert the command line into the following code, replacing `java` with the actual command used, and `/path/to/java` with the output of `which java` (again, use the actual command name if it isn't "java"). The arguments in the command line get inserted instead of `arg1`, `arg2`, etc. Don't use extra quotes; just the characters which form the command-line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
   execl("/path/to/java",
         "java",
         "arg1",
         "arg2",
         /* ... */
         (char*)0);
  /* If we get here, the exec didn't work */
  perror("Failed to execute /path/to/java");
  return 1;
}
```

---

If the untrusted user does not have any other access to the host on which the application is running, the above wrapper could also be used as a "restricted shell"; making it the shell of the user (or otherwise configuring `ssh` so that a login by that user will run the wrapper) will cause an automatic restart on login. However, that's not really a great idea, unless the application knows not to start itself up if it is already running, or can be modified to do this check. Alternatively, the wrapper could be modified to attempt to detect whether the application is currently running before restarting it. Either of these two possibilities involves more details than could be inserted into this answer.

Comment: +1 However, `setuid()`ed shell scripts are (for good reasons) rejected by most modern operating systems.  You'll need to make the wrapper a compiled program.

Comment: @5gon12eder: Ok, inserted a minimal C wrapper which will do it, avoiding all use of the shell (and even of `PATH`).

Comment: That's going to inherit environment parameters, isn't it? They're used for all sorts of things.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline: yes, such as setting the location of the jar files, iirc. That's one of the reasons why I strongly recommend not using `root` as the user-id.

Comment: I realize how old this is, but just wanted to possibly save someone from getting owned: Do NOT use the idea of a setuid hard link to the jvm, as that would allow someone to write a simple Java program to copy the data being protected, and then run it with the privileged jvm.

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely have a file with the executable bit set and the readable bit not and it will do what you expect.  Consider the following program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int
main()
{
  printf("hello, world\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Now you can do

```
$ cc -o main main.c -static
$ chmod 0100 main
$ ls -l
---x------ 1 user user 821801 Sep 28 16:39 main
-rw-r----- 1 user user     75 Sep 28 16:39 main.c
$ ./main
hello, world
$ cat ./main
cat: main: Permission denied
```

The problem with JAR files is that they are not executables.  They are not mapped into RAM by the operating system but *opened and read* by the JVM and it cannot do this without having read permissions set on them.

That said, your concerns are probably unwarranted.  Granting world read permissions on a `*.class` file should be harmless.  They cannot be compromised unless they are writeable which is not needed.  If you store sensitive data like passwords in a `*.class` file, I think you should reconsider that decision.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the OP. It's a response to a comment.

Comment: @rici I wanted to *explain* why it is not possible (using only file system permissions) and argue that it is not needed either.  To be fair, your comment probably refers to a partial state of my since-then edited answer.  Do you think it is still useless?

Comment: I don't think it is impossible, and I don't think you capture the problem (possibly imaginary) which OP has, which is that s/he doesn't want (untrusted user) to *steal* a copy of the jar files, say to install on another machine -- or, at least, that's one possible interpretation of the concern.

Comment: I mean it is impossible by only setting permission bits on the JAR file. Using a `setuid()`ed wrapper is certainly possible.  If “the JAR files get compromised” means the user who executes them knows what he is executing (sounds a strange thing to wish to avoid) then having the JAR world-readable is a problem.  But then again, I'm not sure whether even `setuid()`ing will be a reliable way to prevent `ptrace()`ing the process.

Comment: I don't think you can ptrace a setuid'd executable without root.